# "AxiosError: options must be an object: "ERR_BAD_OPTION_VALUE"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, axios

I am trying to pass an array as a parameter in an axios get.  This is a react application using current packages.

I have used the code per solution to other similar issues.  I have tried applying two different methods/syntax forms, as can been seen from the commented code.

Here is the code:

```js
import Qs from "qs";
import axios from "axios";

console.log(
  "ContactContainer - useEffect[currentUser] - Before check of currentUser.contactRequestsTo.length > 0 ",
  currentUser.contactRequestsTo.length
);
const userIds = JSON.stringify(currentUser.contactRequestsTo);
//const userIds = currentUser.contactRequestsTo;
console.log("ContactContainer - useEffect[currentUser] - userIds ", userIds);
if (currentUser.contactRequestsTo.length > 0) {
  (async () => {
    //const contactRequestsToDetails = await axios.get(`${getUserDetailsRoute}`,{
    //  params: {
    //    arrayOfUserIds: userIds
    //  },
    //  paramsSerializer: (params) => Qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'repeat'})
    //});

    const instance = axios.create({
      paramsSerializer(params) {
        return Qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: "brackets" });
      },
    });

    const contactRequestsToDetails = await instance.get(getUserDetailsRoute);

    console.log(
      "ContactContainer - useEffect[currentUser] - contactRequestsToDetails = ",
      contactRequestsToDetails
    );
  })();
}
```

Some of the package versions as follows:

```
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.0",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

The raw array, currentUser.contactRequestsTo, is:

```
ContactContainer - useEffect[] - currentUser.contactRequestsTo =  
Array(2)
0:"63b476a79c42d2b60fc39cbc"
1:"63b476ea9c42d2b60fc39ccd"
length:2
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)
```

I tried to use the raw array as an input that then applied, JSON.Stringify to the array to get the UserIds shown below:

```
userIds  ["63b476a79c42d2b60fc39cbc","63b476ea9c42d2b60fc39ccd"]
```

I also used the two formats, one is commented out and the other is as shown.

In all cases I received the same error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) 
code:"ERR_BAD_OPTION_VALUE"
message:"options must be an object"
name:"AxiosError"
stack:"AxiosError: options must be an object\n    at Object.assertOptions (http://localhost:8080/static/js/main.d2f30e44.js:2:356049)\
```

I see that other users have experienced the same error and have applied the changes as I interpreted the solutions.

Is there something wrong with my syntax or some other issue that would cause this error?

Comment: You're not passing any params in your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config for `paramsSerializer` changed in v1.0.0. It is now an object with `encode`, `serialize` and `indexes` properties.

If you want to add square brackets to your query parameter arrays, use the following. Also, don't serialise the array to JSON

```js
(async () => {
  const currentUser = {
    contactRequestsTo: [
      "63b476a79c42d2b60fc39cbc",
      "63b476ea9c42d2b60fc39ccd"
    ],
  };
  const getUserDetailsRoute = "https://echo.zuplo.io/"; // just for the demo

  const contactRequestsToDetails = await axios.get(getUserDetailsRoute, {
    params: {
      arrayOfUserIds: currentUser.contactRequestsTo, // the actual array
    },
    paramsSerializer: {
      indexes: false, // empty brackets like `arrayOfUserIds[]`
    },
  });

  console.log(contactRequestsToDetails.data.url);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.2/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-QTnb9BQkG4fBYIt9JGvYmxPpd6TBeKp6lsUrtiVQsrJ9sb33Bn9s0wMQO9qVBFbPX3xHRAsBHvXlcsrnJjExjg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

See https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

---

It's not clear why you feel you need to use `paramsSerializer` at all since `indexes: false` is the default.

Comment: The error on the client side is resolved but I am not getting any parameters on the server side: ``` userController - getDetailsFromArrayOfIds - start - req.params.id =  undefined
userController - getDetailsFromArrayOfIds - start - req.body.arrayOfUserIds =  undefined
userController - getDetailsFromArrayOfIds - start - req.params.arrayOfUserIds =  undefined
userController - getDetailsFromArrayOfIds - start - arrayOfUserIds =  {}
userController - getDetailsFromArrayOfIds - start - req.body =  {}
userController - getDetailsFromArrayOfIds - start - req.params =  {} ```

Comment: @j-terranova you didn't include any information about the request requirements in your question. All I had to go on was the `arrayOfUserIds` param that was in your commented-out code

Comment: @j-terranova works fine for me using `req.query.arrayOfUserIds`. If you wanted the values in `req.params` or `req.body`, why are you passing them as query parameters?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I was looking at the wrong parms.   Works great.